# Некорректно работает псевдоэлемент :before

Tags: css, css3, woocommerce

При добавлении псевдоэлемента `:before` (добавил текст) добавленный элемент дублируется. Не могу понять, почему.

```
.special-grid-home .woocommerce ul.products li.product .price del span {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 100;
  padding-left: 5px;
  color: #333333;
  line-height: 1.3em;
  font-family: 'Istok Web', sans-serif;
  text-decoration: line-through;
  position: relative;
}

.special-grid-home .woocommerce ul.products li.product .price del span:before {
  content: 'старая цена';
}
```

[image: Пример]

Comment: очевидно в элементе del несколько элементов span

Comment: Спасибо, понял. присвоил del:before (без span) и заработало.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Первый раз — перед ценой. Второй — перед знаком рубля.

HTML для цены в вукоммерсе выглядит так:

```
<span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">1999<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">р.</span></span>
```

Получается, что в игре участвуют два вложенных `span`, и псевдоэлемент добавляется к обоим.

Чтобы этого не происходило, используйте в CSS класс, который стоит у нужного вам `span`:

```
.special-grid-home .woocommerce ul.products li.product .price del span.woocommerce-Price-amount:before {
  content: 'старая цена';
}
```

Или [дочерний селектор](https://webref.ru/css/selector/child):

```
.special-grid-home .woocommerce ul.products li.product .price del > span:before {
  content: 'старая цена';
}
```